# Batch file calls another batch when i execute it directly, but not when scheduled

Tags: shell, loops, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this Batchscript (simplyfied, removed all REM-comments and echo-outputs to a txt-file):

```
SET DateTime=%date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr
DEL D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt
dir D:\Interfaces /s /b /a:d /o:n >> D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do DeleteOldFiles.bat %%A
```

The execution works for the first 3 lines, but the 4th line is not executed, or at least, it doesn't enter DeleteOldFiles.bat when runned as a scheduled task.

When I run the script directly in a cmd window, the DeleteOldFiles.bat script is called correctly.

Comment: i changed the dir output to:
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do DeleteOldFiles.bat %%A & echo %%A >> D:\_script_autodel\log.txt

Nevertheless, it still does not work... but i noticed something interesting - maybe this can help to find the solution:

- i changed the 4th line as follows:
  for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do DeleteOldFiles.bat %%A & echo %%A >> D:\_script_autodel\log.txt
- When i run it as a scheduled task, it prints me out the whole array. When i run it directly, it takes line after line as it should

Comment: You are calling `DeleteOldFiles.bat` without path, it is then assumed to be in the working dir, which will be `c:\windows\system32` where it is obviously not found. Make it: `for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do call "D:\_script_autodel\DeleteOldFiles.bat" %%A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working directory when launched from task scheduler will be `c:\windows\system32`. You are not specifying a path to the `batch-file` you are attempting to run, so it is not found. you need to specify the path to the file:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do call "D:\_script_autodel\DeleteOldFiles.bat" %%A
```

you could however skip writing the path everywhere by using `pushd. You can also skip the deletion of the` _folderlist.txt`file if you use single redirect`>` because that will replace the content each time the script is launched.

```
@echo off
set "DateTime=%date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr"
pushd "D:\_script_autodel"
(dir "D:\Interfaces" /s /b /a:d /o:n)>"_folderlist.txt"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (_folderlist.txt) do call DeleteOldFiles.bat "%%~A"
```

Answer (score 1):

First we'll examine your code line by line:

```
SET DateTime=%date:~0% - %time:~0,8% Uhr
```

The above line has issues. First it does not use the correct syntax, `set "var=string value"`. Then it expands the `%DATE%` variable string unnecessarily, as `~0` is everything including the first character. It also prints the first eight characters of the `%TIME%` variable value string, which cannot be known, as its format is user, PC, locale, and language configurable string value. It also, for what seems to me to be a strange reason, suffixes the string `Uhr` to the end. I would have expected that to be included only if you were including the hour, or if ran on a known schedule the hour and minute, not the first eight characters

```
DEL D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt
```

First of all, for best practice, the filepath should always be doublequoted. It does not check if the file exists first, so may generate an error message, if it does not. Also it has no real purpose, because the next line is going to create it if it does not exist, and is going to overwrite it, if it does.

```
dir D:\Interfaces /s /b /a:d /o:n >_folderlist.txt
```

This line once again does not use doublequotes for best practice, and creates a file, which is only required for use in the next command line. It has no purpose beyond that so, we should incorporate it into that next line instead, without creating a file unnecessarily.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt) do DeleteOldFiles.bat %%A
```

The above line has a minor issue, which is, once again, best practice doublequoting: `For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%A In ("D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt") Do …`, and a major one, which is that you are passing each line, one by one to another batch file. The intention is to therefore return to this script, after each one has been processed, so you should use the `Call` command.

All you need therefore is one line:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('Dir "D:\Interfaces" /A:D /B /O:N /S" 2^>NUL') Do @Call "%~dp0DeleteOldFiles.bat" "%%G"
```

Please note, that your code did not define a current working directory, which was a major problem in your script. When ran from the task scheduler, the current working directory, will unlikely be the same as when you invoke it yourself. Therefore I used a full path to your batch file. In this case, I used `%~dp0` to represent the same location for it, as the running batch file. Please replace that, with another absolute path as necessary, e.g. `D:\_script_autodel\DeleteOldFiles.bat`. if it is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The third line of your code places the file "_folderlist.txt" in the current directory.
The other lines use the path "D:_script_autodel"
If current path is different the fourth line will not be able to find the file.

Solution: Change the third line to include the full path for the file.

Comment: This is not the problem. The script is called inside of D:\_script_autodel and the file folderlist.txt is beeing deleted and rebuild... I tried it anyway, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: The Task Scheduler History throws successful messages or return code 0

Comment: OJ is right. When you run your script manually, you are probably in the correct folder. Check the working folder when you run it as scheduled task (it's not what I guess you think it is) Redirect the `dir` output explicitly to `"D:\_script_autodel\_folderlist.txt"`.